# Selecting device (soundcard) to playsound on Delphi

Tags: delphi, audio

How can I select the soundcard to play my sound if I have a PC with two 
soundcards.
now I´m using:

```
procedure TForm_Principal.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
 DevOutCaps: TWaveOutCaps;
 n, i:Integer;
 s: String; 
begin
 Self.comboOut.Items.Clear;

 n := waveOutGetNumDevs;
 for i := 0 to n-1 do
 begin
   waveOutGetDevCaps(i, @DevOutCaps, SizeOf(DevOutCaps));
   s := PChar(@DevOutCaps.szPname);
   Self.comboOut.Items.Add(s);
 end;
end;
```

And then:

```
procedure TForm_Principal.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  Res: TResourceStream;
begin
  Res := TResourceStream.Create(HInstance, 'Sound_Ringing', RT_RCDATA);
  try
    Res.Position := 0;   
    PlaySound(Res.Memory,
    Self.comboOut.ItemIndex, SND_MEMORY or SND_ASYNC );
    //SndPlaySound(Res.Memory, SND_MEMORY or SND_ASYNC or SND_LOOP);
  finally
    Res.Free;
  end;
end;
```

And it doesn't work, anyone can help me?
Thank you.

Comment: i think you better to drop ancient (pre-1995) waveOut API and use something more modern. For example you may use DirectX. Usualyl it is used in Delphi via **DSPack** library by Henri Gourvest. I heard in recent Delphi versions they distribute it as a part of Delphi, for earlier versions you would have to download and install it. At least, most modern video players like KMPlayer, BSPlayer, MPC-HC, etc are based on DirectX and do offer to select non-default audio output

Comment: Also they say that starting with Vista and new independent-channels sound manager those old APIs are not suited well for music playback - they can easily be preempted by any other sound event wit hhigher priority. So one better to use "Windows Audio Session API" aka WASAPI. Other argues (example: http://www.aimp.ru/blogs/?p=214#more-214) that DirectX is no worse than WASAPI even in Windows 7. Chose yourself. PS: http://stackoverflow.com/tags/dspack/info